# Is a using declaration for a non-member type equivalent to an alias declaration with an identifier equal to the terminal name of the using declarator?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, using-declaration, alias-declaration

In short, I'm asking if doing

```cpp
using foo::bar::baz;
```

has the same effect as

```cpp
using baz = foo::bar::baz;
```

(Clearly I'm assuming that `foo::bar::baz` names a type that is not a class member, e.g. I'm referring to something like `namesapce foo::bar { using baz = int; }`, and not to something like `namespace foo { struct bar { using baz = int; }; }`.)

I'm pretty sure they are two different things (otherwise they could also always stay side by side, which is not the case, as I know that the former can't be in a `struct`/`class`, unlike the latter), but how do I read it from the standard? I was looking at [[namespace.udecl]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#nt:using-declarator) and [[dcl.pre]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:alias-declaration), but I can't really draw a conclusion.

Comment: What is "non-class memeber type"?

Comment: Do you mean that `foo::bar::baz` refers to a type that is not a member of the current class or its base classes, i.e. that `foo::bar` is not a base class? If so, https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#3.sentence-1 simply forbids this use inside as a member declaration.

Comment: `using foo::bar::baz;` lets you use `baz` without qualifying it.  `using baz = foo::bar::baz;` introduces a new name called `baz` that is an alias of `foo:bar::baz`.  You get the same behavior (can use `baz` without qualification) but the way you get there is different.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/77Tnh7cx9

Comment: @Evg, what I mean is that `foo` is a namespace and `bar` is a namespace nested in it, i.e. neither of them is a class.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer, a few words about it?

Comment: _a few words about it?_ You mean, key references? http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#5 (where «denote different entities» seem to also include «one name denotes an entity, the other is a _typedef-name_») + http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#4.1 (or, rather, in the /(4.1)→/5 order) (I could not find normative wording saying that a _using-declarator_ introduces its _unqualified-id_, only http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#2.sentence-2, but I think the intent is clear. Asked D. Herring)

Comment: BTW, you tag C++20, but link the current draft, which «contains» P1787

Comment: _I could not find normative wording saying that a using-declarator introduces its unqualified-id … Asked D. Herring_ This is already known issue

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely differences between the two, but most of them are of **no interest** to most programmers.  For example,

```
namespace N {
  struct X {};
  struct Y {};
  struct Z {};
}
namespace O {
  int X,Y;
  using N::X;    // OK
  struct X x;    // OK, finds N::X
  int i=X;       // OK, finds O::X
  using Y=N::Y;  // error: conflicts with “int Y”
  using Z=N::Z;
  struct Z z;    // error: elaborated-type-specifier with typedef-name
}
```

One practical distinction is in **exporting** a previously declared name with module linkage:

```
module A:S;
struct S {};
```

```
export module A;
import :S;
export using ::S;  // error: “struct S” has module linkage
export using S=S;  // OK
```

The *using-declaration* can of course also be applied to non-type declarations, whereas the *alias-declaration* can also be a template.

Comment: How does `export using T=T;` conflict with `struct T`?

Comment: @duck: You’re right; it doesn’t.  I amended the example appropriately; thanks.